# Occasional Freeze at Boot

Tags: boot, freeze

My recently installed Ubuntu (and ALL the other distros I used before) sometimes (not-always) hangs on boot.
 It's a hard-to-debug problem because it just happens 'sometimes' (I never know when the boot will hang).
 When the problem arrives, the screen STOPS in a "Ubuntu purple" empty screen, just after the "purple GRUB" screen. In the other distros, the boot used to stop in a black screen, which appears in the EXACTLY same point of the "Ubuntu purple" screen.
 I'm relatively new to the GNU/Linux world, so please, be patient.

Comment: What happens when it freezes? You have to restart the pc or does it hang and resume? Also, have you tried switching discs, memory, etc.

Comment: It is a notebook and when it freezes, I have to hold the POWER OFF button to force a hardware shut down. I forgot to mention that I have dual-boot Windows/Ubuntu and that when the laptop freezes, I see no disk activity.

Answer (score 2):

To debug more, I advise to change the boot options so that the boot is more verbose.

If you edit (as root, with `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`) you can see a line somewhere with is similar to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

remove "quiet" (or the two of them to have an old-style, no graphic, verbose boot) and save. Then you have to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now your system will be much more verbose on boot, and maybe you can see where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks! But the biggest challenge now is to wait for the problem to come up, because the "freeze" is a little rare (and extremely annoying).

Comment: Yes --- but this is unavoidable. I had an old system where it happened sometime only on reboot (not poweroff) and was solved by adding "reboot=pci" in the kernel command line. Another laptop in my office will sometime freeze if booted with the splash screen but never without it. Say thanks to BIOS writers...

Comment: I'm begining to suspect that the 'freeze' happens when I turn on the laptop and it is relatively "cold", that is, it spent a lot of time turned off. Any tips if that's the case?

Comment: Can't think anything short of a slow-starting disk(s)... maybe adding a delay to GRUB?

Comment: Oh! That seems to be a great idea. I'm going to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Xubuntu 12.04.4 LTS](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04.4/release/) and see if you experience the same hang/freeze issues. You can install Xubuntu on a linux partition or you can test it on a NTFS partition in Windows with [Wubi](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/wubi.exe). If you use wubi.exe to install Xubuntu do not allocate more than 30GB for the virtual disk(s).

I got rid of a similar problem with yours after replacing **lightdm** with **mdm** . Now I have MDM as default display manager, and the login greeter for mdm can be customized in all possible ways, and I like it better than the Unity Greeter which enters into low graphics mode everytime you make a tiny adjustment to your default Ubuntu settings.

Comment: Xubuntu was one of the distros I've tried before checking out Ubuntu, and unfortunately, the same 'freezing' problem occured on Xubuntu. I believe that what is happening here is a sort of "distribution-independent" problem.

Comment: Computer doesn't even get to the login manager part. This was better of as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Have you always used the 64bit version of Ubuntu or other distros? Maybe you can try the 32bit version.

Comment: I always used 64bit versions, but I never thought it could be a problem. Thanks for the tip!